# Additional information on Ocean Modifier

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

I'm currently doing research on ocean waves at a University and using Blender Ocean Modifier to test a method developed for estimating parameters of the ocean from video. I'm using real video and the simulated one to test.

I am obligated to be familiar with the internal mechanisms of how the ocean is rendered in Ocean Modifier, meaning is a specific ocean energy spectrum, such as the Phillips spectrum, used in order to get the simulation.

Also, if there is any additional documentation apart from the user manual, something a bit more detailed about the ocean modifier.

Just a sentence of which algorithms, spectrum are used is enough for my purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: The integration of the Ocean modifier was done by Matt Ebb, maybe he can help you further with this. See https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Simulation/Ocean/ for history, parameters and reference.

Comment: Hi aliasguru, thank you for your answer. You helped me track the information, which is that the rendering of deep ocean waves in the Hudini toolkit uses the algorithms of Jerry Tessendorf described in the SIGGRAPH 2004 course notes. That is, the Phillips energy spectrum is used for the creation of the ocean waves.